# Get the percentage of a number for width

Tags: php, math

I am creating a horizontal bar chart with html/css/php. The first value is supposed to be 100% and will have a width of 425px. Every value after that (which is lower) needs to have it's width calculated as a percentage of 425px.

So say the first value is 63 and gets a width of 425px (100%). I need to figure out the next's width if the next is 50, then 31, 27 and so on...

I'm fine with markup, etc. it's the math calculation I'm trying to get my head around.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but its a bit off topic, being a question about  basic maths rather than programming!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function calc_width($max_width, $max_value, $value) {
    return $max_width * $value / $max_value;
}
```

Because `$value / $max_width` is the appropriate fraction, you can just multiple the maximum width by that fraction to get the appropriate width for later values.

Comment: Thanks for the example and description Amber!

Answer (score 2):

Divide total by 100

multiply by the percentage

eg

```
425 / 100 = 4.25

25% = 4.25 x 25
```

Answer (score 1):

Divide the highest number by 100 to get one percentage, then multiply by the needed amount of percentages.

```
$maxWidth = 425; //The highest width
$onePercentage = $maxWidth / 100; //Calculate one percentage
$values[31] = $onePercentage * 31; //Times 31
```

Answer (score 1):

It's tempting to just say "divide by 100% and multiply by the percentage", but this is **incorrect** since it will result in inaccuracies over the long run. The correct way to do this is to maintain an array of widths and percentages, and calculate each width from the beginning and from the previous cumulative width.

An example if you will, of splitting 29px into four pieces of 25%:

> 29px * 25% = 7px
>   4 widths of 7px equals **28px** total

And with cumulative calculations:

> 29px * 25% = 7px
>   29px * 50% = 15px
>   29px * 75% = 22px
>   29px * 100% = 29px
>   4 widths of 7, 8, 7, 7px equals **29px** total